# How to set an object as nullable in Javascript (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, null

I keep getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'doors' of null`. I want to be able to set `doors` to be nullable, as to be able to avoid this error and simply hit the error response and return 404. However, I am not sure how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
Data.findOne({
        '_id':'6182544c20d538aefe49def0',
        'doors.id':doorId  
    }, {
        'doors.$':1
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send('No Matching Door Found')
        } else if (data.doors[0].status === 'open') {
            res.status(401).send('Door already unlocked')
        } else {
            res.status(200)
        }
    })
```

The error is hit on the third line, where It cannot find a doors object where the ID is equal to `doorId`.

I have tried setting `doors.id` to `!doors.id`, however, this then kept hitting the 404 regardless of what was being entered.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's JS error. You can use optional chaining `data?.doors[0].status` to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that your entire query is wrong.
I would suggest first to try this query for your needs:

```
Data.findOne({
    '_id':'6182544c20d538aefe49def0',
    'doors.id':doorId  
}, {
    'doors.$':1
}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(404).send('No Matching Door Found')
    } else if (data.doors[0].status === 'open') {
        res.status(401).send('Door already unlocked')
    } else {
        res.status(200)
    }
})
```

Then I recommend you to read more about MongoDB and Mongoose.